# PyCUDA demo example error on OSX 10.9.2 + CUDA 5.5 + EDP 2.7.3

Tags: python, macos, cuda, pycuda

I'm getting a pycuda runtime error (very similar to the one at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078191/opencv-2-4-7-mac-osx-10-9-python-2-7-6-cuda-5-5) as below. The error when executing the example is

```
cordelia:examples xxx$ python demo.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pycuda.driver as cuda
  File "/Users/xxx/canopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycuda-2013.1.1-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/pycuda/driver.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pycuda._driver import *

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/xxx/canopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycuda-2013.1.1-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/pycuda/_driver.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcurand.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/xxx/canopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycuda-2013.1.1-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/pycuda/_driver.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _driver.so requires version 1.1.0 or later, but libcurand.dylib provides version 0.0.0
```

and it shows up again on the command line, stopping my show for now:

```
Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.3 | 64-bit | (default, Aug  8 2013, 05:37:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

> > > import pycuda._driver

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/xxx/canopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycuda-2013.1.1-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/pycuda/_driver.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcurand.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/xxx/canopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycuda-2013.1.1-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/pycuda/_driver.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _driver.so requires version 1.1.0 or later, but libcurand.dylib provides version 0.0.0
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are installing from an egg compiled for OS 10.6, which clearly won't work (hint look at the egg name).

Comment: So the pip version is out of date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the steps at [http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Installation/Mac#Step_3:_Install_PyCUDA](http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Installation/Mac#Step_3%3a_Install_PyCUDA) worked - phew!